# Invalid Collation name Integration Services (SSIS) Profiling task Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, collation

I am trying to do a profiling task over a database that uses `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC` as collation name. When I try to add a quick profile over a table it shows the error

```
    Error at Profiling Task [Data Profiling Task]: Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC is an invalid collation name.
    Parameter name: collationName
```

What does this means ? How can I do the profiling that I need without changing the collation of the database (I need that particular one) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of SQL?

Comment: SQL EXPRESS 2014

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) 
 Jun 10 2015 03:35:45 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: is that a migrated database?

Comment: No, but  I have restored it from backup

Comment: can you run this SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;

Comment: master SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

tempdb SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

model SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

msdb SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

SIMBA Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC

FILES Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC

STG_SIMBA Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC

Comment: i see. normally you'll have a collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS for all database and apply Supplementary Characters when filtering but only to a number of data types...

Comment: So I need to set the collation same for all databases ?

Comment: yes.. collations are used for string matching as a standard but can be extend over the queries

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support

> Introduced in SQL Server 2012, a new family of supplementary character
>   (SC) collations can be used with the data types nchar, nvarchar, and
>   sql_variant. For example: Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC, or if using a
>   Japanese collation, Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_100_CI_AS_SC.

> The database collation is used for all metadata in the database, and
>   is the default for all string columns, temporary objects, variable
>   names, and any other strings used in the database. When you change the
>   collation of a user database, there can be collation conflicts when
>   queries in the database access temporary tables. Temporary tables are
>   always stored in the tempdb system database, which uses the collation
>   for the instance. Queries that compare character data between the user
>   database and tempdb may fail if the collations cause a conflict in
>   evaluating the character data. You can resolve this by specifying the
>   COLLATE clause in the query.

My suggestion is to change the collation to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS and run profiling.